# passing parameter to object box query

Tags: flutter-objectbox

I am new to object box.  I am struggling on finding a way to pass parameters to my query. i looked at the documentation but still struggling.

this is my code

```
late Stream<List<dynamic>> _stream;

_stream =  _Mystore
        .box<Income>()
        .query()
        .watch(triggerImmediately: true)
        .map((query) => query.find());

return StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
      stream: _stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final activeIncomes = snapshot.data;

        if (!snapshot.hasData || activeIncomes!.length == 0) {
          return  Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: noData()
          );
        }
        return itemList(activeIncomes!);
      },
    );
```

the above query will get all the rows from entity Income. however, i want to filter the rows by passing parameters value. I tried the following but didnt work

```
late Stream<List<dynamic>> _stream;

_stream =  _Mystore
        .box<Income>()
        .query()
        .watch(triggerImmediately: true)
        .map((query) => query.param.(Income_.monthNumber.equals(6))find());
```

i added param.(Income_.monthNumber.equals(6)   to query but i get error.
The argument type 'Condition' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QueryProperty<dynamic, dynamic>'.

can someone help me and show me how to add parameters to query in objectbox so that i can use that query with my stream?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pass conditions to the `query()` method. Using your example:

```
box().query(Income_.monthNumber.equals(6))
```

Source: https://docs.objectbox.io/queries